# Is there a way to add legend and count to each level for geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, legend

[image]

Is there a way to add a legend with the count to give density of each row?

Or an easier way to show it?

Thanks very much!

Couldn't even get a legend added :)

Code I used:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = subscribed, y = campaign)) +
  geom_point () +
  geom_jitter()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could per group (subscribed) create a `label` which is calculated beforehand the number of `n()` observations and assign these as a column string. This can be used in the `aes` to make sure it is shown in the legend. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  group_by(subscribed) %>%
  mutate(count = paste0(subscribed, ' (n = ', n(), ')')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(subscribed, campaign, colour = factor(count))) + 
  geom_jitter()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Created data:

```
df <- data.frame(campaign = runif(100),
                 subscribed = rep(c("no", "yes"), 50))
```

Comment: Perfect does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to show similar data to this, in a more clear manner.

However, I couldn't figure out the legend lol

The code I used was :

```
 p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = subscribed, y = pdays)) +
  geom_count() + scale_size_continuous(range = c(7, 30))

p + geom_text(data = ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]], 
              aes(x, y, label = n), color = "#ffffff") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30, by = 4))
```

[image]